# C++ application automated build within different environments

Tags: c++, build, continuous-integration, build-process

Current Situation:
We have an application written in C++, build with cmake, unit testing with googletest.

We have two environments:

- Test: a local less powerful server
- Production: several Amazon EC2 instances with a pre-built AMI image

We test on local machine and when we do release, we checkout code on production machine, build it and run.

Now company is promoting CI with automated build tools(eg. Jenkins).
While we can automate our build process, but some people suggest that it's not recommended to build directly on production machine.

But in my humble opinion, unlike Java program can run as long as there is JRE, C++ application is highly machine dependent.

Docker maybe a silver bullet most of the cases but unfortunately our application cannot be put into docker as it needs to run on a cluster of real machines.

Is there a general/common way in industry to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: IMHO as long as the image is same, the application will behave the same. So I would set up a local vm with the same image and first test on it and/or make another amazon instance (not so powerful) and test and build it there and them move the binary to production system. Building directly on a production environment can potentially break the service, and may use a lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `Staging` (or `Pre-production` or whatever name you desire) environment for the CI system using the same class of servers as `Production` but without interfering with the `Production` servers.

Once you're happy with the `Staging` results you can then safely deploy on `Production`.

The argument that running the CI system itself may interfere with testing on the same server still applies to the `Staging` environment (I'm not sure if I correctly understood this as a part of the concerns). The only way around it would be a `CI` environment dedicated only to the CI system operation (running the CI infra, building, etc). The class of servers in this `CI` environment only matters for the CI system performance. The CI system should be able to handle the test verifications on remote environments like `Staging` or `Production` which aren't impacted by the CI operation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to guess why your application has a real need of hardware/server but my first bet would be docker, and it is awesome. We do something similar and works very nicely integrated with github, bamboo, stash and docker. The best part is scalability and dependencies are nicely contained and build breakages are quickly identified.

Another approach I have seen in my past is where you have various build machines/servers on which a common fileserver is mounted and whenever a push occurs in git, a local service is invoked which picks a server with lowest CPU load and builds code on that machine (though the code lives in a common fileserver)